# How can I rig the pelvis to deform properly?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

Does anyone know a rigging setup for the pelvis? I've been looking through a "ton" of tutorials on YouTube but they're either out of date, don't provide enough info, or they just don't work etc. And I know you can just click on preserve volume, but I want to do it on certain body parts, for precise deformation. I also Tried Metarig, but the crotch on that rig still doesn't look good either.[image]

Comment: Add two bones to mimic the pelvic bone and preserve the volume. if you have used Rigify's metarig then please note that this armature is only used to fit the bones of the animation rig to the mesh. It's not used for animation. The actual animation rig is created when you hit the "Generate Rig" button. Here is an example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/275168/107598